# Cannot boot Windows 10 after 22H2 update

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-update

I have an old laptop that is not eligible for Windows 11, so it stays on Windows 10. Recently it would not boot, and thinking it was the hard drive, I replaced the hard drive with a new SSD. I reinstalled Windows 10 from a bootable USB, and proceeded to install all updates, but then it would not boot again! So I tried to narrow things down following these steps:

1. Delete all partitions on the drive
2. Reinstall Windows 10
3. Verify rebooting works fine, verify shutting down / starting up works fine.
4. Create System Restore Point.
5. Install all Windows updates, except the most recent.
6. Verify rebooting etc works, create another restore point (same as Steps #3 and #4)
7. Install the latest update, "Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5034122)".
8. Reboot -> But here it failed to start!
9. Using USB boot media, tried Startup Repair, but it "couldn't repair your PC"
10. Used the bootable USB to restore to the previous System Restore points (I tried each one).
11. Reboot -> But it still fails!

When it fails to start, it does not show the Windows loading screen or the Windows loading spinner at all. It just boots to a blank screen.

The latest windows update appears to make a change to the system that a System Restore cannot fix. Anyone know what's going on?

Lenovo G580, x64, 4GB RAM, new 1TB SSD drive

Comment: Have you tried booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: To resolve, boot to WinRE's command prompt, or boot an InstallUSB and once the GUI loads, press `Shift`+`F10` to open a terminal: `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD` _(**UEFI:** remove `&& BootRec /FixBoot` and use `bcdboot` instead to rebuild the boot directory)_ - once `/RebuildBCD` completes, reboot. [KB5034122](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/january-9-2024-kb5034122-os-builds-19044-3930-and-19045-3930-7656c6a4-0b06-4424-86a9-d0719f4ac252) is a security update, and unless the OS is BSODing, 99% of boot issues can be resolved with `BootRec`.

Comment: @e7eth I am not able to boot into Safe Mode because I cannot enter WinRE. Restarting 3x does not trigger it because it never gets to the Windows loading screen.

Comment: @JW0914 I have UEFI and tried this: `BootRec /FixMBR` -> "The operation completed successfully", `bcdboot C:\Windows` -> "Boot files successfully created.", `BootRec /RebuildBCD` -> "Scanning all disks .... Total identified Windows installations: 0 ... The operation completed successfully". Is that right? It still will not boot unfortunately.

Comment: @JW0914 I got it to boot! I reformatted the System Partition, then did bcdboot + rebuildbcd (based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di?view=windows-11#repair-the-system-partition)). However, this only worked after doing a System Restore. If the 22H2 update is installed, these steps don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sometimes happens that a particular Windows update doesn't
work for a specific hardware/software configuration.
In most cases, Microsoft may update it after the problem
is signaled and will publish a new update.
Sometimes the new update will supersede the problematic one,
but sometimes it will have the same name but not the same
contents.

If that update is making your computer unbootable,
you may block it.
Microsoft doesn't favor your doing so, but it has in
the past published a tool for doing that, called
"Show or hide updates", which you may
[download from Microsoft](https://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/2/f22d5fdb-59cd-4275-8c95-1be17bf70b21/wushowhide.diagcab).

With this tool, you may hide the problematic update from
Windows Update. Microsoft has labelled this tool as
"deprecated", but it's still working.
There exist also alternative tools, although all use the
same basic Windows technology.

After a few months you could try it again, but better
take good backups before doing that.

You may find a detailed description of using the tool
in the article
[How to Hide/Stop/Block Specific Updates on Windows 10/11?](https://www.minitool.com/news/how-to-block-specific-updates-on-windows-10-11.html)

Comment: Wouldn't `bootrec` be helpful?

Comment: @JW0914: Helpful in what sense? The computer is said to boot well without that last update.

Comment: There is absolutely no chance that Windows 10 22H2 would be incompatible with a device that can run Windows 11. Considering the author installed 22H2 and it was running. The much simpler explanation is something else happened

Comment: @harrymc [KB5034122](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/january-9-2024-kb5034122-os-builds-19044-3930-and-19045-3930-7656c6a4-0b06-4424-86a9-d0719f4ac252) is a security update, and unless the OS is BSODing, 99% of boot issues can be resolved with `BootRec`; short of a BSOD, the Windows boot process is straight forward _(there's a diagram of the entire boot process on Microsoft Learn, previously Microsoft Docs)_ and a security patch is unlikely to make Windows 10 unbootable since the main causes of Windows being permanently unbootable is OS system file corruption or incompatible drivers

Comment: @JW0914: None of us know what exactly goes wrong when this update is installed. There is no reason that a security update will impact upon the boot process, which is why I hesitate with BootRec. It can of course do no harm to try it.

Comment: Thank you harrymc! I got it to boot with a System Restore, followed by deleting the System Partition, following by commands suggested by @JW0914. Those steps do not work with the update installed, so now I'm using the wushowhide tool to block the update, and I'll try again in a few months.